# Swift Async Networking. How do I RETRY on error?

Tags: swift, firebase, api, networking, async-await

I have created a generic networking function using async which is working fine, but I would like to be able to retry the request if it throws an error, if the Token is expired for example. How would I do this without having to change all my DO Catch?

```
func request<T: Codable>(_ endpoint: Endpoint) async throws -> T {
    
    guard let url = endpoint.url else {
        throw NetworkError.badURL
    }
    
    guard let token = idToken else {
        throw NetworkError.invalidToken
    }
    
    let request = buildRequest(from: url, methodType: endpoint.methodType, idToken: token)
    
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
        
        //RETRY X AMOUNT OF TIMES <<<
        
        throw NetworkError.invalidResponse
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    guard let result = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
        throw NetworkError.decodingError
    }
    
    print("Result: \(result)")
    
    return result
}
```

Comment: Put the do catch inside the function and only throw when you are ready to throw.

Comment: Please forgive a completely unrelated observation: You might want to reconsider whether you really want to retry on any non-2xx response. E.g., if the web service had some internal error of 5xx, do you really want to retry? We can't comment further without knowing why you want to retry, but retrying on any non-200 response may be too broad.

Comment: Also, another unrelated observation: I would strongly advise against `try? decoder.decode(…)`, because if there is a decoding error, you are discarding essential diagnostic information that tells you _why_ it failed. Personally, I would just `try` and let it throw the actual error that `JSONDecoder` provided, or give your `decodingError` an associated value (perhaps the original error) with the necessary diagnostics. As responses get more complicated, figuring out why decoding failed is hard enough as it is; the error thrown by `decode` will tell you exactly where the problem rests.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I appreciate it. That makes sense. I actually only want to retry if the token is expired/ I get a 401. Looking into this led me down a rabbit hole of considering making multiple calls in case of temp network issues https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/retrying-an-async-swift-task/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this, I would suggest writing a rendition of `data(for:delegate:)` that wraps the retry logic, e.g.:

```swift
extension URLSession {
    func data(for request: URLRequest, delegate: URLSessionTaskDelegate? = nil, maxRetries: Int) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse) {
        for _ in 0 ..< maxRetries {
            let (data, response) = try await data(for: request, delegate: delegate)
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            if 200..<300 ~= response.statusCode {     // as an aside, note, any 2xx response is success
                return (data, response)
            }
        }

        throw NetworkError.invalidResponse
    }
}
```

Then, you can replace:

```swift
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
    
    //RETRY X AMOUNT OF TIMES <<<
    
    throw NetworkError.invalidResponse
}
```

With:

```swift
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request, maxRetries: 3)
```